# Are there any online tools available for entering Korean text?

Tags: hangul

This issue came up somtime during the commitment phase. How do I go about entering Hanguel?

Answer (score 10):

To start entering Hanguel in a Windows computer, we first need to get the Microsoft Korean IME

A good step-by-step guide to installing the IME is here:

http://www.declan-software.com/korean_ime/korean_ime.htm#korean_vista

This is for Windows Vista, but it should be similar for other Windows versions

Here's the layout for a standard Korean keyboard

[image]

The 한/영 button switches between Hanguel (한) and English (영) modes

The 한자 button doesn't to anything in most standard installation, but it is meant to enter the Hanja (Chinese character) entry mode

**Online options**:

Currently the easiest option is Google's online on screen keyboard at google translate

Go to Google translate and select Korean as the current language

Click on the keyboard icon and select Korean

[image]

The On-Screen Keyboard will appear

Click on the characters you want, they will appear in the Google translate text-box, then copy and paste them to wherever needed

Other useful online tools:

https://www.branah.com/korean

http://sori.org/hangul/conv2kr.cgi

In a Korean Windows installation, Shift+Space bar acts as the 한/영 key as well

Comment: May also be worth pointing out that if you don't have a 한글 toggle key on your keyboard, your Right Alt key will usually *become* that key and toggle languages.

Comment: Also, there are Hangul keyboard stickers on ebay if you need some help start learning to type Hangul.

Comment: Any such software for Mac available?

Comment: @bravokeyl OS X (or macOS or whatever it's called now) *does* have a built-in Korean IME that is very easy to use. After enabling it, you can use Command+Space to toggle input languages (and tools like Karabiner let you remap that to something else if you want)

Comment: @dotVezz , great! just enabled

Comment: Also for those that dont have admin to change keyboard settings, you can use [this website](https://www.branah.com/korean) which is ok when you need to type on someone elses computer

Comment: @너구리 for what it's worth, that website is actually already in this answer.

Comment: please post the Mac thing as an answer, as we also need to improve the answer/question ratio during private  beta

Comment: Hello. This edit http://korean.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/150 should not have been approved. Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed gmail added an IME. A quick search found [Google Input Tools](http://www.google.com/inputtools/try/). It creates a draggable keyboard with different language layouts, including Korean.

You can use the online version without installing anything. There are also options to install as a Chrome extension or PC application. (Might be an MacOS option if it auto-detects OS?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Naver SE](http://se.naver.com/) converts any keyboard input into Korean as if you were typing on a standard Korean keyboard. No need to install anything. (Make sure to press the keyboard icon, first. Otherwise keyboard input is not converted). You can also input with the mouse, but they have some interesting layouts...

[image]