# Is there any program for Microsoft Windows for dictating Korean text?

Tags: pronunciation

Neither Dragon NaturallySpeaking nor Microsoft Speech Recognition allows dictation to Korean text. Is there any program for Microsoft Windows for dictating Korean text?

I am aware that there exist some online solution, such as Google dictation in Google Documents, but as far as I know it only allows to dictate within the browser.

Comment: Crazily enough, I think this might belong on [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @dotVezz I asked here because I saw http://korean.stackexchange.com/q/171/3

Comment: I wondered if that was it. I think this is a case where the scope of the question has maybe *just* left the realm of on-topicness. In my opinion, an edit to give it some kind of emphasis on *learning* the language might satisfactorily move it back into on-topic territory. Maybe "Are there any TTS tools for helping me learn pronunciation?" or something like that?

Comment: @dotVezz The other question has no more learning component than this one. I opened some meta question http://meta.korean.stackexchange.com/q/42/3 IMHO no preference, just would prefer voting to be more consistent.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, and (just from my perspective on the voting patterns) I think that the votes reflect the reality that hangul input is naturally much more directly connected to the process of learning the langauge than a TTS software is. That said, I'm happy to let the community reach a consensus on how to treat questions like this and think that the meta question is a good idea - because your question is *absolutely* useful, and it'd be nice if we can find a way to use it and others like it.

Comment: @dotVezz Well, in the meantime I posted the question on Quora https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-there-any-program-for-Microsoft-Windows-for-dictating-Korean-text?share=1

Answer (score 2):

(I haven't tried this so my apologies if it doesn't work)

Google Now appears to have support for Microsoft Windows and is supported by 52 languages (one of them being Korean). I believe you can [download its equivalent](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/google/9wzdncrfj2gk) on Microsoft Windows via the Microsoft Store and have it as an app on your PC (the Google app, there are 2 but the other doesn't appear to have support for Windows), given that you're running 8.1 or greater. I'm not aware of all of its capabilities as I haven't tried it, but maybe this can act as at least a partial solution.

Under 'Supported Languages' on the linked webpage is "한국어(대한민국)". The app lists its capabilities as "Use your location, Use your microphone, Access your Internet connection". More specifically on the voice dictation, under 'Features' the app says it has "Voice Search - Use your microphone to ask Google anything and see the answer instantly."

---

EDIT: If this doesn't work, then after extensive search I would vouch that at the moment there isn't any program on Windows capable of doing what you want.